# Using could not for possibility/impossibility

Tags: modal-verbs, would, could

Can I use ''could not'' form to say that somebody would not be capable of doing something?

Example:

> He was a popular singer back in the 90's. But I'm sure that he couldn't fill a concert hall (now).

Is is better to say :

> He was a popular singer back in the 90's. But I'm sure that he would not be able to fill a concert hall (now).

I know that the posititive form - could- expresses possibility but does the negative form - could not- do the same thing.

Comment: As far as I can tell the two meanings are identical, and both would be acceptable from a style point of view.

Comment: 'He couldn't fill a concert hall (now)' means 'He would not be able to fill a concert hall (now)' and not 'It is possible that he wouldn't fill a concert hall (now)'. 'He could fill a concert hall (now)' is, however, ambiguous.